# Selenium syntax for xpath in Python

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to click on text at this url http://ecos.fws.gov/ecp0/profile/speciesProfile?sId=6994, but can't come up with the right syntax.

What I want to do is click on "View All", but unfortunately there are multiple "View all"s in the html. The html looks like this:

```
<li style="margin-bottom:1em;">
<p><strong>Population location:</strong>Â Wherever found west of Mobile and Tombigbee Rivers in AL, MS, and LA</p>
<p><strong>Listing status:</strong>Â 
                    <span class="listingThreat">Threatened</span>
</p>
<ul>
<ul>
<li><b>States/US Territories</b> in which this population is known to or is believed to occur:Â 
    <a href="/ecp0/profile/countiesByState?entityId=181&amp;state=Alabama" onclick="window.open('', 'popup', 'width=800,height=550,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes')" target="popup">Alabama</a>
    , <a href="/ecp0/profile/countiesByState?entityId=181&amp;state=Louisiana" onclick="window.open('', 'popup', 'width=800,height=550,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes')" target="popup">Louisiana</a>
    , <a href="/ecp0/profile/countiesByState?entityId=181&amp;state=Mississippi" onclick="window.open('', 'popup', 'width=800,height=550,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes')" target="popup">Mississippi</a>
</li>
<li><b>US Counties</b> in which this population is known to or is believed to occur:Â 
    <a href="/ecp0/profile/countiesBySpecies?entityId=181" onclick="window.open('', 'popup', 'width=800,height=550,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes')" target="popup">View All</a></li>
<li><b>USFWS Refuges</b> in which this population is known to occur:Â 
    Bogue Chitto National Wildlife Refuge, Egmont Key National Wildlife Refuge, Grand Bay National Wildlife Refuge, Hobe Sound National Wildlife Refuge, Mississippi Sandhill Crane National Wildlife Refuge<br/>
</li>
</ul>
</ul>
</li>
```

I basically need to select where li style is "margin-bottom:1em;" and contains  both "Threatened" and "View All". Unfortunately, for the url provided, there are two "View Alls", and both are within a li of style = "margin-bottome:1em;".

I just can't think of a way to uniquely identify the first "View All". I am thinking some kind of conditional path, but not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this xpath out - `"//span[@class='listingThreat']/ancestor::li//a[text()='View All']"`

Comment: That worked perfectly. I am going to have to look up the /ancestor::li. I haven't seen that used with xpath.